# string item in WHERE clause on JSONB column list

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

For a given table:

```
CREATE TABLE books (  
  book_id serial NOT NULL,
  data jsonb
);
```

With value:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, '["fantasy", "horror"]');
```

How to select row where "fantasy" is an item of data column ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# select * from books where data @> '["fantasy"]';
 book_id |         data          
---------+-----------------------
       1 | ["fantasy", "horror"]
```